# Lambda trigger is not working as intended with bulk data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-comprehend

I'm using lambda triggers to detect an insertion into a **DynamoDB** table (Tweets). Once triggered, I want to take the message in the event, and get the sentiment for it using **Comprehend**. I then want to update a second **DynamoDB** table (SentimentAnalysis) where I ADD + 1 to a value depending on the sentiment.

This works fine if I manually insert a single item, but I want to be able to use the **Twitter API** to insert bulk data into my **DynamoDB** table and have every tweet analysed for its sentiment. The lambda function works fine if the count specified in the Twitter params is <= 5, but anything above causes an issue with the update in the SentimentAnalysis table, and instead the trigger keeps repeating itself with no sign of progress or stopping.

This is my lambda code:

```
let AWS = require("aws-sdk");

let comprehend = new AWS.Comprehend();

let documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = (event, context) => {

    event.Records.forEach(record => {

        if (record.eventName == "INSERT") {

            //console.log(JSON.stringify(record.dynamodb.NewImage.tweet.S));

            let params = {
                LanguageCode: "en",
                Text: JSON.stringify(record.dynamodb.NewImage.tweet.S)
            };



            comprehend.detectSentiment(params, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("\nError with call to Comprehend:\n " + JSON.stringify(err));
                } else {
                    console.log("\nSuccessful call to Comprehend:\n " + data.Sentiment);


                    //when comprehend is successful, update the sentiment analysis data
                    //we can use the ADD expression to increment the value of a number
                    let sentimentParams = {
                        TableName: "SentimentAnalysis",
                        Key: {
                            city: record.dynamodb.NewImage.city.S,
                        },
                        UpdateExpression: "ADD " + data.Sentiment.toLowerCase() + " :pr",
                        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                            ":pr": 1
                        }
                    };


                    documentClient.update(sentimentParams, (err, data) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error("Unable to read item " + JSON.stringify(sentimentParams.TableName));
                        } else {
                            console.log("Successful Update: " + JSON.stringify(data));
                        }
                    });


                }


            });

        }
    });
};
```

[This is the image of a successful call, it works with the first few tweets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXXD6.png)

[This is the unsuccessful call right after the first image. The request is always timed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpNb5.png)

Comment: You should consider using the promisified variants of all AWS SDK calls. For example: `const rc = await comprehend.detectSentiment(params).promise();`

Comment: What do the CloudWatch Logs tell you? Did the function timeout or fail? What is the function timeout value set to?

Comment: @jarmod I'm learning to use amazon services, and I had no idea there was a timeout value. I tried promises before, and they changed nothing. However, my timeout was set to 3 seconds. I increased the time and everything seems to be working fine. Thank you! P.S - This is my first question and I have no idea how to mark you as the correct answer since this is a comment.

Comment: Hi @Dan, my reference to using promises was not specifically to resolve this problem, but an FYI that you should consider using promises rather than callbacks. There aren't many good reasons to use callbacks for new code any more. Looks like you accepted Jason's answer so all good. Going forward, it's worth getting comfortable with CloudWatch Logs as a way to debug Lambda functions. PS you can upvote comments, but not accept them as answers. If they add something valuable, upvote them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeout is why it’s happening repeatedly. If the lambda times out or otherwise errs it will cause the batch to be reprocessed. You need to handle this because the delivery is “at least once”. You also need to figure out the cause of the timeout. It might be as simple as smaller batches, or a more complex solution using step functions. You might just be able to increase the timeout on the lambda.

Comment: Increasing the timeout on the lambda worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Nice, it would also be worthwhile to check if your sentiment table is given the required IOPs to avoid lambda from failing from "Throughput Exceeded Exceptions. "